# How to remove whitespace before and after braces, the } { characters, in vs studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default in VS studio code there is a rule for whitespace format like this:

```
import { foo } from './foo';
```

I want to remove white space to:

```
import {foo} from './foo';
```

How can I do this in vs studio code preferences?

Answer (score 2):

Try these settings:

```
 "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,

  "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
"editor.trimAutoWhitespace": true,
```

in User Settings. 
(Accessible via Command Palette -> Preferences:Open User Settings)